# Let $X$ be a topological space and $\mathcal{A}= \{f: X \to X \mid f \text{ continuous}\}$. Determine the topology that $\mathcal{A}$ induces on $X$.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $X$ be a topological space and  $\mathcal{A}= \{f: X \to X \mid f \text{ continuous}\}$. Determine the topology that $\mathcal{A}$ induces on $X$.

The definition I found for the induced topology by collection of maps is that it is the collection $\{f^{-1}_i (V) \mid V \subset X \}$ where $V$ is an open set. If each $f_i$ is continuous then for any $V$ open in $X$ we have that $f^{-1}_i (V)$ is open. And as $$f^{-1}_i (V)=\{x \in X \mid f(x) \in V\}$$ I think we have that the singletons are open which would imply that the induced topology is the discrete one, but I don't know if this is true?

Comment: In fact the *correct* definition for the incuded topology is the topology with **subbase** $\{f^{-1}[O]: f \in \mathcal{A}; O \in \tau_X\}$.

Comment: Wouldn't this still give the discrete topology?

Comment: no, we get a subset of $\tau_X$ by definition.

Comment: Every $f^{-1}(V)$ is open in the standard topology, and as $f$ can be the identity, every standard open set can be obtained this way. Conclude

Comment: The induced topology is just the one $X$ already had.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The induced topology $\tau_i$ by $\mathcal A$ has subbase

$$\mathcal S=\{f^{-1}[O]; f \in \mathcal{A}; O \in \tau_X\}$$

by definition.

If $U=f^{-1}[O] \in \mathcal{S}$ then $U \in \tau_X$ because $f$ is continuous on $X$ (as $f \in \mathcal A$). So it follows that $\tau_i \subseteq \tau_X$.

OTOH, if $U \in \tau_X$, then $1_X^{-1}[U]=U \in \mathcal S \subseteq \tau_i$ because the identity $1_X \in \mathcal A$, always. Hence $\tau_X \subseteq \tau_i$.

**Conclusion:** the induced topology is *precisely* the topology on $X$ that we started out with.